# How to add/edit the comment of a partitioned column in Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning

I have a Hive table with partition on a column 'part_col' and I would like to add comment to this column 'part_col'.

I have tried the below ALTER statement but it does not work and throws error,

```
ALTER TABLE comment_test PARTITION (part_col) RENAME TO PARTITION (part_col string COMMENT 'new_comment');
```

Are there any other way to add or modify Hive table column's partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Comment can be added to a partition column at the time of creation of the table. (as shown in Example [1]).
2. Adding or modifying a partition column's comment need to be done in the Metadata database due to the nature of design of Hive partitions. `ALTER` statements can be used to change the values of the partition column such as Example [2] but not the name of the partition itself.

[1] Comment to a partition at the time of creation of table:

```
CREATE TABLE comment_test
(id STRING COMMENT 'comment1',
description STRING COMMENT 'comment2')
PARTITIONED BY (part_col STRING COMMENT 'partition_comment');
```

[2] Statement to modify the value of a partition. (Not the partition column name)

```
ALTER TABLE comment_test 
PARTITION (part_col='501') RENAME TO PARTITION (part_col='503');
```

[3] Query to add/modify partition comment after the table has been created. (To be run in HMS Backend DB and NOT in Hive)

```
UPDATE PARTITION_KEYS 
SET PKEY_COMMENT='new_comment' 
WHERE TBL_ID=<TBL_ID of the table of interest> ;
```

To get TBL_ID, run the below query in the HMS backend DB,

```
SELECT TBL_ID 
FROM TBLS 
WHERE TBL_NAME='<name of the table for which the partition change is needed>';
```